# what is Via in HTTP Response and how to remove it?

Tags: php, curl, iis-7, webserver, iis-7.5

I made a `curl` request to a `PHP` file on my server from my machine and it returns the following response.

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Length: 317
Content-Type: application/json
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
Last-Modified: Wed, 19 Feb 2014 11:30:16 GMT
Via: 1.1 SC10100_83_75
Connection: keep-alive
Date: Wed, 19 Feb 2014 12:00:47 GMT
```

The problem is, this seems to be caching my request and is not returning the latest values. I suspect it is due to the Via header (read that it is about proxies). What is it and how can I remove it?

Comment: As a simple google search shows the `Via` header is the signature of a proxy. That also explains why things might be cached: this is what a proxy often is used for.

Comment: A simple thing to do (assuming you have no control over the infrastructure) is to add a "cachebuster" parameter to the URL you are requesting.  E.g. add `&cachebuster=<<timestamp>>` to the end of the URL, where `<<timestamp>>` is a number based on the current time (e.g. php's `time()`)

Comment: I actually have control over the infrastructure because I am running Amazon EC2 and I have admin access. I dont remember deliberately enabling it, how can I disable the proxy then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like via - indicates that you have been routed via a proxy - however - this is information only - you need to make sure you caching headers are being set correctly so that the proxy takes the correct action.

Currently there is no caching headers being set on your request.

If you do not want it to be cached - then set the following header:

```
Cache-Control: no-cache
```

See http://www.w3.org/Protocols/HTTP/Issues/cache-private.html

Comment: there seems to work once I set the headers manually. however I am calling the php file from Objective-C. is there a way to set no-cache as the default on the web server?

Comment: depends on the web server - i am no expert on IIS - however if you can modify the PHP script you just need to add the header command - http://ie2.php.net/manual/en/function.header.php

Comment: Looks like you can set default headers in IIS too http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753195(v=ws.10).aspx

Comment: Actually, it doesnt seem to be a web server fault either because I tried to `curl` the same file on `localhost` and it worked just fine. it's just that for some reason it is going through a proxy when I am requesting for the file from externally.

Comment: If the server you need to connect to is going to be accessed via a proxy - then you really do need to set the the headers correctly.  It is best practice to do so anyway - as there are many proxies lurking on the internet.  If the proxy is permitted to cache - then the web server will not even get visibility of the request.

Comment: I set the `Cache-control` to `no-cache` for the folder. I just tried to curl using the IP address instead of the domain name and that seems to work. Is some DNS screwing me up? I tried to flushcache but that didnt help.

Comment: Where did you obtain the IP from - the DNS may be mapped to route to a different IP.   You are still going to be best served to set the cache control headers correctly if you can.